# What's wrong with this HQL? “Returning Null value for selecting an Entity in a join query"

Tags: hibernate, null

```
session.createQuery("select ccrd.createdDate , s1 "
+  "from  CrComponentRelDependency ccrd "   
+  "left outer join ccrd.crComponentDependencyDtls s1 "   
+  "where ccrd.crComponent.componentSeq= :COMPONENT_SEQ " 
+  "and (ccrd.referencedComponentVer IS NULL) "
 .setParameter("COMPONENT_SEQ", componentId);
```

This query is giving valid values for *ccrd.createdDate* , but it is returning NULL for *s1* entity.
I have defined a one-to-one relation between ***CrComponentRelDependency*** & ***crComponentDependencyDtls***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL does all the joining for you, so *don't* explicitly join tables. Try this:

```
session.createQuery("select createdDate, crComponentDependencyDtls "
+  "from CrComponentRelDependency ccrd "   
+  "where crComponent.componentSeq = :COMPONENT_SEQ " 
+  "and referencedComponentVer IS NULL")
 .setParameter("COMPONENT_SEQ", componentId);
```

Note also the removal of unnecessary qualification and brackets from your HQL.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, thanks for the suggestion. I tried the above query, but it will always return a valid date for the createdDate field and a null for the second value. Am i missing something?

Comment: You haven't posted enough info for me to help further. As it was, I guessed most of it. I don't know what your table layout is nor what data you have.